# Flink kafka connector 0.11.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to get on Flink kafka connector 0.11 but it keep throwing me this error when running the job.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while confirming checkpoint
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task$3.run(Task.java:1260)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ProducerFencedException: Producer attempted an operation with an old epoch. Either there is a newer producer with the same transactionalId, or the producer's transaction has been expired by the broker.
```

As I understood from kafka documentation the transaction timeout must be larger than the checkpoint interval, but smaller than the broker transaction.max.timeout.ms.

My cluster has setup as below:

- Flink version 1.4.2
- Application with flink-connector-kafka-0.11_2.11
- Checkpoint interval : 5000ms
- Observed End-to-end checkpoint time: 2s

Kafka producer config:

```
transactional.id : tx-kafka-topic1
transaction.timeout.ms : 30000
acks: all
enable.idempotence : true
retries: 3
max.in.flight.requests.per.connection : 1
```

Kafka broker (kafka_2.11-1.0.0-cp1.jar) with server config:

```
transaction.max.timeout.ms=120000
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
```

It seem to me the interval are not overlapped with each other, but the job still failed with error above. Appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: What's the timing of the events? Maybe the problem is with the first checkpoint, which happens after pipeline initialisation and simply the initialisation is taking longer then 30 seconds?

It could be helpful if you shared full Flink application logs.

Comment: My pipeline overview as 
source --> flatmap --> RichMap(with thread.sleep(100ms) delay each record ) --> Sink

The reason for the 100ms is to slow down the pipeline for exception handling testing.
Does the event time will cause the transaction time/ checkpoint related timeout? thanks.